# How to align in in the middle the html div?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I've been looking for this in google and it says that the css code is `margin: 0 auto;`. I tried it and it doesn't work for me. Please help. Thanks in advance.

**`login.html`**

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Log In</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="formLogin">
    <table class="formTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Username: </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="loginusername" name="loginusername"/>  </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password: </td>
            <td> <input type="password" id="loginpassword" name="loginpassword"/>  </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" id="btnlogin" name="btnlogin" value="Log In"/>
        <input type="submit" id="btncancelogin" name="btncancelogin" value="Cancel"/>
    </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**`stylesheet.css`**

```
table.formTable {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

table.formTable td {
 padding: 8px;
}

#formLogin {
 width: 360px;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius:    10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius:         10px;
}
```

Comment: I think you'd better strip down your code example to the most basic form and also include an example of what you want and some explanation of what you already tried.

Comment: Right, what are you trying to accomplish??

Comment: I want the entire div("formLogin") to be vertically in the middle of the browser.

Comment: what browser you are viewing it in?

Comment: It seems that your code works for me fine? Table with Login form is centred in the middle of the page. Not vertically though. Do you want to centre it vertically?

Comment: vertically? if you want to do that you should not have a margin-top and margin-bottom of 0. check out w3schools for the short notation of the margin directive.

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash Yes, vertically centered.

Comment: @JohnKrommidas I forgot to mention that I already tried margin-top: 0 and margin-bottom: 0 but failed.

Comment: Check my answer there is a link to a nice article about vertical centering. Hope it will work for you!

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash The prolem with the example is the height is fixed. If the browser changes its size the div is not already in the middle.

Comment: Check my answer again. I put in some code there for you. Hope it works :). Apologies for delay, I got distracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to center it vertically also try reading [this](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html).

Update:

Try this code. Of course you can move CSS out to your css file. Tested in IE9 and FF6:

```
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Log In</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper{
    background-color: #ccf;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;

    }
#content{   
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 900px; 
}
table.formTable {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

table.formTable td {
 padding: 8px;
}

#formLogin {
 width: 360px;
 background-color: #eeeeee;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px;
 -moz-border-radius:    10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius:         10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
 <div id="formLogin">
    <table class="formTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Username: </td>
            <td> <input type="text" id="loginusername" name="loginusername"/>  </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Password: </td>
            <td> <input type="password" id="loginpassword" name="loginpassword"/>  </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" id="btnlogin" name="btnlogin" value="Log In"/>
        <input type="submit" id="btncancelogin" name="btncancelogin" value="Cancel"/>
    </div>
 </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Hachi says try `text-align:center;` but you could also add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    width:100%;
}
```

This will give your page a width, so your elements will have a width to use.

Update:

Didn't realise you wanted it vertically centered too. You could put the whole thing in a table cell and use `valign="middle"` to center it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about ***DOCTYPE***. Have try to put ***DOCTYPE***

HTML 5

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
```

HTML 4

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
```